# Transform this iteration function to recursive

Tags: javascript, recursion, iteration

This is a function to display the sum of the input digits with iteration perspective:

```
function sumOfDigits(number) {
    let strNumber = number.toString()
    let output = 0;
    for(i=0;i<strNumber.length;i++){
      let tmp = parseInt(strNumber[i])
      output = output + tmp
    }
    return output
}

// TEST CASES
console.log(sumOfDigits(512)); // 8
console.log(sumOfDigits(1542)); // 12
console.log(sumOfDigits(5)); // 5
console.log(sumOfDigits(21)); // 3
console.log(sumOfDigits(11111)); // 5
```

I am wondering how we write this function in a recursive way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the modulo operator, you can get the remainder (which in the case of a divison by 10, is the last number) and then add the next iteration.

```js
function sumOfDigits (n) {
    if (n === 0) return 0
    return (n % 10 + sumOfDigits(Math.floor(n / 10)))
}

console.log(sumOfDigits(512))
```

If you want to see a more detailed explanation, check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-digit-number-using-recursion/

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested it,  but you can try the following without casting to string

```
function sumOfDigits(number) 
{ 

    if (number === 0) {
       return 0; 
    }

    return (number % 10 + sumOfDigits(Math.floor(number / 10))); 
}
```

Make sure that the input is indeed in number format

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
function sumOfDigitsRecursive(number){
    let strNumber = number.toString()
    if(strNumber.length<=0)
       return 0
    return parseInt(strNumber[0])+sumOfDigitsRecursive(strNumber.slice(1,strNumber.length))
}
```